# Compilation and Output issues in Visual Studio Code (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner in C++ and I'm still a huge noob. My current problem with Visual Studio Code is that, unlike in Python or Linux bash, I do not see the output of my C++ program anywhere. I downloaded a compiler (I'm sure I downloaded several ones that I can't remember, but clang is definitely there) and I can see the output window that shows this when I press CTRL+Alt+N (Run Code) in a Hello, world! program:

```
    [Running] cd "c:\Users\<USER>\Desktop\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\<USER>\Desktop\"main
    'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
    [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.076 seconds.
```

I have so many questions...

1. First of all, why g++? I tried downloading GNU before and it DID NOT WORK
   for some reason. Why g++ now? I have clang. Why does it even mention
   g++ when it's apparently compiling without problems in the Problems
   tab? I don't get this...
2. When I press F5 (Start Debugging), I get
   a pop up menu with two options: C++ (GDB/LLDB) and C++ (Windows).
   None of them work, when I press on them a new tab called
   settings.json opens with the follpwing text:

   ```
   {
       "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark",
       "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "D:\\Programs\\LLVM\\bin"
   }
   ```

Why does this tab even open and why do I get no output?

3. Back to the main problem, where can I see the output of my program? By output I mean seeing "Hello, World!" when I write and compile a Hello World program and not just [Done] executed in blah blah seconds. It is definitely not in the output tab and I am so confused I don't know where to find it or if it even exists in Visual Studio Code. I am sorry I'm still a big noob and have stupid questions, but could someone ELI5 to me what the problem is?

Comment: try following the official guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: VSCode requires some extra setup to work with C++, especially on windows. Personally I absolutely love VSCode, but for beginners I recommend instead Visual Studio Community. It's free and works out of the box with C++.

Comment: first learn how to create a program from your C++ source from the command line, then you can look into how to configure VSC to do it for you.

Comment: @bolov I've already installed the c++ extensions plus a code runner one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.